# application with identifier 'xxx' was not found in the directory 'xxx'

Tags: angular, azure, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory, adal

I have an Angular 2 application, which at the moment runs in a website environment.

I had setup an Azure AD App as a Web Application to use single sign on. The app was set as multi-tenant and I was able to log users in from different tenants with no problem, given that an admin has first granted permission using the admin_consent option.

I am now trying to compile this app as a native ios, windows and android application using Cordova. I was unable to do this as I cannot set a Redirect URL because it runs in a native environment.

I have now tried to setup the app as a native application. I have read from multiple sources that native applications are multi-tenant by default however, I am now unable to login with using an account on a separate tenant because I am getting the error

`application with identifier 'xxx' was not found in the directory 'xxx'`

I am using the using the adal library and I am sending the request to common, I have also updated the manifest file to set:

`"oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,`

and

`"availableToOtherTenants": true,`

Comment: I can't reproduce your scenario,could you please share your detail steps or something i haven't noticed?

Comment: @NanYu-MSFT it's working now, must have been a browser cache after restarting the browser I no longer experienced this issue. Have another issue now with redirect URL, because it cannot be set in Cordova, seen a few others have this issue as well